# Why is this to the power of $\frac{3}{2}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I was reading [Paul Nylander's website](http://www.bugman123.com/Fractals/index.html) and I  read about this thing called the "magnetic pendulum fractal". Essentially, imagine a pendulum whose bob is made of a magnetic metal and placed above some magnets. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQeQwwXXa7A) for the actual experiment. Paul Nylander's website gives this equation for the pendulum's position:

$\begin{align*} m\ddot{\mathbf{x}} = \sum_j \frac{\mathbf{r}_j}{(h^2 + \mathbf{r}_j \cdot \mathbf{r}_j)^{3/2}} - g\mathbf{x} - \mu\dot{\mathbf{x}} \end{align*}$

In this equation:

- $\mathbf{x}$ is the position of the pendulum bob in the x-y coordinate plane. (The bob is assumed to be locked to a plane some fixed height above the plane the magnets lie on.)
- $\mathbf{r}_j$ is the distance between the bob's position and that of the $j$th magnet, i.e. $\mathbf{r}_j := \mathbf{x}_j - \mathbf{x}$, where $\mathbf{x}_j$ is the center of the $j$th magnet.
- $h$ is the height of the bob above the magnets.
- $g$ is the kickback force of the pendulum (think Hooke's law).
- $\mu$ is friction/air resistance.
- $m$ is the bob's mass.
- We assume the magnets are of equal strength.

I'm trying to understand this equation and I understand most of it. From what I understand, the $-g\mathbf{x}$ term comes from Hooke's  law, and describes the force restoring the pendulum back to its state of rest. The $\mu\dot{\mathbf{x}}$ term just damps the velocity. We put it all together using Newton's second law.

However, I don't understand why the denominator in the summation is raised to the power of $\frac{3}{2}$. [This source](https://www.math.hmc.edu/%7Edyong/math164/2006/win/finalreport.pdf) says it's to eliminate the vertical component from what is obviously a distance formula in the equation, but I don't see why that is. From what I understand, magnetic force obeys Coulomb's law, which is essentially a type of inverse square law. So why is there a 3 here?

Please try to keep in mind that I don't know too much about electromagnetics. Thanks for your help.

Comment: [Because magnets are dipoles](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293310).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: Glad to help. Here's [one more link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Magnetic_dipole%E2%80%93dipole_interaction).

Comment: Perhaps this is better asked on https://physics.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still the inverse square law, as the full expression for this term is
$$
\frac{{\bf r}_j}{\|({\bf r_j},h)\|^3}
=-\nabla_{{\bf r_j}}\frac1{\|({\bf r_j},h)\|}
$$
so the power 1 in the numerator and the power 3 in denominator cancel to an overall power of $-2$. The dipole expression usually has the power 5 in the denominator

Comment: What does that subscript under the gradient symbol mean?

Comment: That not the full gradient is computed, but only the partial derivative for the variables in the subscript. The full gradient might, depending on interpretation, also contain the partial derivatives for $h$. This is not a unique use of that place. In other contexts it may indicate the direction for a directional derivative.